# JQuery using the click event handler. How do I keep all the elements from not show only have one element show one at time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jquery using the click event handler. How do I keep all the elements from not show but only have one element show one at time to what is related when I click on it?.

My example page: http://chrism.net46.net/final-ff-IX/summoners-paintings.html

Using a image map. I have ten "hot spots", each a monster painting and 10 `div`s with information about each painting. When I click a hot spot I just a lightbox with info about that page segment to open.

I have used jquery plugins like jquery tools with success, but I'd like to learn how without using a plugin.

Anyway here is a video example what I mean starting at 0:15 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7628mBPumM4 hope this is more clear.

Here http://jsfiddle.net/muThj/1/ without the image map, though. Using it to host the code review just in case the above link site goes down due to traffic.

```
<img src="wall-writings.jpg" alt="Eidolon mural paintings of Curbuncle, Madeen, Ramuh, Shiva, Ark, Ifrit, Leviathan, Phoenix, Fenrir, Atomos" usemap="#eidolonpaintings"> 
        <map name="eidolonpaintings">
        <area shape="poly" coords="287,230,301,244,319,251,329,252,340,252,347,252,338,246,336,237,344,233,344,229,345,225,356,227,362,229,376,230,385,235,393,242,396,250,403,254,408,248,414,239,419,231,424,224,429,222,433,233,432,248,428,263,422,272,422,279,410,286,396,288,388,291,385,293,390,296,393,305,396,316,400,318,407,320,414,325,416,332,420,343,415,352,414,360,408,369,401,374,405,387,409,399,407,409,408,412,402,414,368,365,357,374,358,390,359,403,354,409,343,415,337,416,323,370,294,362,268,327,264,274,287,230" >
        <area shape="poly" coords="628,253,617,222,624,172,630,149,647,109,667,81,681,66,694,53,720,49,756,48,768,53,775,75,825,99,924,135,981,154,1019,169,912,266,795,312,747,372,670,335,628,253" >
        <area shape="poly" coords="1018,196,1029,182,1040,174,1043,167,1043,153,1045,138,1059,132,1076,137,1079,159,1082,176,1090,189,1110,249,1127,269,1132,286,1127,303,1146,380,1150,400,1136,409,1095,417,1067,418,1046,415,1029,405,1009,409,988,405,974,399,967,391,977,348,994,275,988,264,1018,196" >
        <area shape="poly" coords="1173,125,1176,116,1168,110,1163,101,1168,83,1167,75,1153,73,1148,61,1159,52,1165,46,1172,41,1192,33,1202,33,1213,33,1220,37,1233,38,1248,40,1259,54,1254,65,1227,71,1227,80,1218,93,1228,105,1231,116,1230,137,1228,152,1225,175,1217,184,1209,195,1195,219,1196,235,1197,245,1190,250,1180,248,1140,204,1130,191,1173,135,1173,125" >
        <area shape="poly" coords="1269,1,1302,41,1320,59,1322,73,1316,86,1310,105,1310,114,1317,125,1324,133,1325,149,1322,179,1317,196,1311,207,1303,217,1292,207,1288,221,1284,238,1279,254,1281,270,1281,290,1290,294,1306,314,1316,334,1312,349,1311,363,1313,383,1295,407,1285,418,1284,429,1272,438,1274,458,1285,459,1336,463,1369,461,1457,465,1488,463,1513,467,1482,429,1493,406,1474,366,1475,330,1474,287,1469,276,1479,254,1478,235,1472,216,1469,183,1469,166,1475,149,1477,129,1473,123,1475,118,1482,85,1504,53,1536,3,1536,-1,1269,1" >
        <area shape="poly" coords="1482,301,1516,347,1510,371,1526,396,1550,409,1568,418,1583,442,1614,470,1622,481,1633,479,1673,487,1709,480,1716,448,1724,369,1728,331,1739,296,1713,265,1699,250,1681,228,1652,233,1619,235,1584,237,1528,273,1482,301" >
        <area shape="poly" coords="1719,222,1747,160,1751,143,1726,149,1724,132,1717,119,1712,97,1687,86,1636,33,1643,28,1687,47,1772,41,1823,2,1843,1,1858,35,1914,50,1976,37,2082,87,2080,100,1911,119,1879,141,1829,136,1836,158,1852,180,1859,200,1849,225,1825,238,1811,266,1819,284,1837,301,1843,304,1847,325,1823,309,1805,285,1797,263,1816,228,1829,220,1818,214,1790,201,1773,192,1762,180,1735,214,1719,222" >
        <area shape="poly" coords="2051,147,2074,125,2080,118,2094,113,2107,106,2131,112,2169,84,2231,92,2254,107,2273,130,2274,147,2264,161,2265,179,2269,214,2235,215,2174,208,2189,172,2160,165,2140,161,2115,180,2102,198,2091,204,2071,208,2061,205,2053,197,2083,180,2094,172,2087,161,2065,168,2052,168,2051,147" >
        <area shape="poly" coords="1847,298,1896,265,1988,240,2041,232,2044,253,2096,251,2082,273,2105,287,2091,329,2065,349,2079,377,2049,390,2032,397,2018,420,2070,456,2050,477,1986,437,1960,421,1957,460,1939,460,1908,408,1904,438,1871,448,1876,402,1857,410,1811,435,1803,430,1844,392,1864,359,1875,335,1865,324,1847,298" >
        <area shape="poly" coords="2332,1,2523,1,2535,23,2548,38,2541,50,2534,69,2524,79,2528,101,2524,159,2511,208,2503,272,2482,295,2479,344,2452,393,2434,394,2419,427,2387,422,2368,407,2351,351,2341,300,2337,213,2330,201,2312,201,2308,170,2307,153,2326,143,2341,115,2348,90,2342,81,2338,64,2332,1" >
        </map>

    $('area').attr('href', '#');
    $('.off-the-side').addClass('push-side');

    $('.wall-writings').addClass('wall-writepos').prepend('<button class="close"><img src="x-icon.png" alt=""></button>').hide(); 

    $('area').click(function(){$('#writing1').fadeIn('slow');return false;});

    $('.close').click(function(){$(".wall-writings").fadeOut();});
```

Comment: Please make a bigger effort in making this more clear...I don't understand your question myself, and I'm sure others don't as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood the problem :)

I would place an href tag on each area like:

```
   <map>
    <area href="#div1" shape="poly" coords="287,230,301,244,319,251,329,252,340,252,347,252,338,246,336,237,344,233,344,229,345,225,356,227,362,229,376,230,385,235,393,242,396,250,403,254,408,248,414,239,419,231,424,224,429,222,433,233,432,248,428,263,422,272,422,279,410,286,396,288,388,291,385,293,390,296,393,305,396,316,400,318,407,320,414,325,416,332,420,343,415,352,414,360,408,369,401,374,405,387,409,399,407,409,408,412,402,414,368,365,357,374,358,390,359,403,354,409,343,415,337,416,323,370,294,362,268,327,264,274,287,230" >
    </map>
<div id="some_div">Some text</div>
$('area').click(function(){var href = $(this).attr('href'); $(href).show(); return false;});
```

css

```
#some_div{display:none;}
```

I think this should work. If this is not what you intended please explain further

Comment: Thanks jribeiro I'll try that :). I don't have internet access at my house right now. sooo if it doesn't work... tomorrow afternoon i will try to explain it more clearer. Just case people miss it: the example page: copy/paste (..http://chrism.net46.net/final-ff-IX/summoners-paintings.html..)

Answer (score 0):

> In jquery using the click event handler. How do I keep all the
>   elements from not show but only have one element show one at time to
>   what is related when I click on it?.

From what i can deduce from your html mapping, you are missing the id's attribute for the  tag and your Jquery is actually targeting the whole image map.

the guilty code:

```
 $('area').click(function(){$('#writing1').fadeIn('slow');return false;});
```

Because of that, all the elements would show when you clicked on any of the area map.